# How to access Kibana dashboard via HAproxy

Tags: elasticsearch, reverse-proxy, haproxy, kibana-4, devops

I am having a server which is running kibana & i have set it to be accesses from localhost. This is a linux server so i can do :

```
 links http://localhost:5601
```

This runs fine. I need to put this kibana server behind HAProxy which will act as a reverse proxy for Kibana.

My Haproxy config file (/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg) looks like

```
global
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
        stats timeout 30s
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

        # Default SSL material locations
        ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
        crt-base /etc/ssl/private

        # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
        # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
        #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
        ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
        ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull

        option  http-keep-alive
        timeout http-keep-alive 5m
        timeout http-request 5s
        timeout connect 300s
        timeout client  300s
        timeout server  300s
        timeout check   300s


        #timeout connect 5000
        #timeout client  50000
        #timeout server  50000
        errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
        errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
        errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
        errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
        errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
        errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http


listen stats 0.0.0.0:9000       #Listen on all IP's on port 9000

    #This is the virtual URL to access the stats page
    stats uri /haproxy_stats

    #Authentication realm. This can be set to anything. Escape space characters with a backslash.
    stats realm HAProxy\ Statistics

    #The user/pass you want to use. Change this password!
    stats auth admin:passwordhere

    #This allows you to take down and bring up back end servers.
    #This will produce an error on older versions of HAProxy.
    stats admin if TRUE
```

What frontend & backend should i be adding to this file, i am more interested in context based switching. I am looking for "http://haproxy_ip/kibana" should redirect me to kibana web page

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please add below code to `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg`
Now `http://haproxy_ip/kibana` will open kibana dashboard.

```
listen  http-port80 *:80
    mode   http
    reqirep ^(accept:\ .*)(http://www.wapforum.org/xhtml,)(.*) \1"http://www.wapforum.org/xhtml",\3
    acl acl_kibana path_beg /kibana
    use_backend kibana if acl_kibana

backend kibana
    mode   http
    reqirep ^(accept:\ .*)(http://www.wapforum.org/xhtml,)(.*) \1"http://www.wapforum.org/xhtml",\3
    balance roundrobin
    server  kibana **kibana_server_ip**:5601 weight 1 maxconn 512 check
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
frontend main *:80
  acl url_kibana   path_beg   -i /kibana
  use_backend kibana   if url_kibana

backend kibana
  mode http
  reqrep ^([^\ ]*)\ /kibana[/]?(.*) \1\ /\2
  server x.x.x.x:5601
```

Test the HAProxy config:

```
haproxy -c -V -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```

Restart the HAProxy:

```
systemctl restart haproxy
```

The original answer and explanation at: [kibana server.basePath results in 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36266776/kibana-server-basepath-results-in-404)