# kibana server.basePath results in 404

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

I am running kibana 4.4.1 on RHEL 7.2

Everything works when the kibana.yml file does not contain the setting `server.basePath`. Kibana successfully starts and spits out the message

```
[info][listening] Server running at http://x.x.x.x:5601/
```

`curl http://x.x.x.x:5601/app/kibana` returns the expected HTML.

However, when basePath is set to  `server.basePath: "/kibana4"`, http://x.x.x.x:5601/kibana4/app/kibana results in a 404. Why?

The server successfully starts with the same logging

```
[info][listening] Server running at http://x.x.x.x:5601/
```

but

`curl http://x.x.x.x:5601/` returns

```
<script>
  var hashRoute = '/kibana4/app/kibana';
  var defaultRoute = '/kibana4/app/kibana';
  ...
</script>
```

`curl http://x.x.x.x:5601/kibana4/app/kibana` returns

`{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found"}`

Why does '/kibana4/app/kibana' return a 404?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`server.basePath` does not behave as I expected.

I was expecting `server.basePath` to symmetrically affect the URL. Meaning that request URLs would be under the subdomain /kibana4 and response URLs would also be under the subdomain /kibana4.

This is not the case. `server.basePath` asymetrically affects the URL. Meaning that all request URLs remain the same but response URLs have included the subdomin. For example, the kibana home page is still accessed at http://x.x.x.x:5601/app/kibana but all hrefs URLs include the subdomain /kibana4.

`server.basePath` only works if you use a proxy that removes the subdomain before forwarding requests to kibana

Below is the HAProxy configuration that I used

```
frontend main *:80
   acl url_kibana   path_beg   -i /kibana4
   use_backend kibana   if url_kibana

backend kibana
   mode http
   reqrep ^([^\ ]*)\ /kibana4[/]?(.*) \1\ /\2\
   server x.x.x.x:5601
```

The important bit is the `reqrep` expression that removes the subdomain /kibana4 from the URL before forwarding the request to kibana.

Answer (score 0):

Also, after changing server.basePath, you may need to modify the nginx conf to rewrite the request, otherwise it won't work. Below is the one works for me

```
        location /kibana/ {
            proxy_pass http://<kibana IP>:5601/; # Ensure the trailing slash is in place!
            proxy_buffering off;
            #proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
            #access_log off;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The below config files worked for me in the k8s cluster for efk setup.

Elastisearch Statefulset: elasticsearch-logging-statefulset.yaml

```
# elasticsearch-logging-statefulset.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: es-cluster
  namespace: logging
spec:
  serviceName: logs-elasticsearch
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: elasticsearch
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.5.0
        resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1000m
            requests:
              cpu: 500m
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: rest
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: inter-node
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data-logging
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        env:
          - name: cluster.name
            value: k8s-logs
          - name: node.name
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: discovery.seed_hosts
            value: "es-cluster-0.logs-elasticsearch,es-cluster-1.logs-elasticsearch,es-cluster-2.logs-elasticsearch"
          - name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
            value: "es-cluster-0,es-cluster-1,es-cluster-2"
          - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
            value: "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      initContainers:
      - name: fix-permissions
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data-logging
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - name: increase-vm-max-map
        image: busybox
        command: ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
      - name: increase-fd-ulimit
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "ulimit -n 65536"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data-logging
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "standard"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 100Gi

---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: logs-elasticsearch
  namespace: logging
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
spec:
  selector:
    app: elasticsearch
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - port: 9200
      name: rest
    - port: 9300
      name: inter-node
```

Kibana Deployment: kibana-logging-deployment.yaml

```
# kibana-logging-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kibana
  labels:
    app: kibana
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kibana
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kibana
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kibana
        image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.5.0
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1000m
          requests:
            cpu: 500m
        env:
          - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS
            value: http://logs-elasticsearch.logging.svc.cluster.local:9200
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5601
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: "/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml"
            subPath: "kibana.yml"
            name: kibana-config
      volumes:
        - name: kibana-config
          configMap:
            name: kibana-config




---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: logs-kibana
spec:
  selector: 
    app: kibana
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 5601
      targetPort: 5601
```

kibana.yml file

```
# kibana.yml
server.name: kibana
server.host: "0"
server.port: "5601"
server.basePath: "/kibana"
server.rewriteBasePath: true
```

Nginx kibana-ingress: kibana-ingress-ssl.yaml

```
# kibana-ingress-ssl.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kibana-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"  
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: basic-auth
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: 'Authentication Required - admin'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 100m
#    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - example.com
#      # This assumes tls-secret exists adn the SSL
#      # certificate contains a CN for example.com
      secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: logs-kibana
            port:
              number: 5601
        path: /kibana
        pathType: Prefix
```

auth file

```
admin:$apr1$C5ZR2fin$P8.394Xor4AZkYKAgKi0I0
```

fluentd-service-account: fluentd-sa-rb-cr.yaml

```
# fluentd-sa-rb-cr.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  labels:
    app: fluentd
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  labels:
    app: fluentd
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  - namespaces
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: fluentd
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: fluentd
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: fluentd
  namespace: default
```

Fluentd-Daemonset: fluentd-daemonset.yaml

```
# fluentd-daemonset.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  labels:
    app: fluentd
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: fluentd
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: fluentd
    spec:
      serviceAccount: fluentd
      serviceAccountName: fluentd
      containers:
      - name: fluentd
        image: fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1.4.2-debian-elasticsearch-1.1
        env:
          - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
            value: "logs-elasticsearch.logging.svc.cluster.local"
          - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
            value: "9200"
          - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME
            value: "http"
          - name: FLUENTD_SYSTEMD_CONF
            value: disable
          - name: FLUENT_UID
            value: "0"
          - name: FLUENT_CONTAINER_TAIL_EXCLUDE_PATH
            value: /var/log/containers/fluent*
          - name: FLUENT_CONTAINER_TAIL_PARSER_TYPE
            value: /^(?<time>.+) (?<stream>stdout|stderr)( (?<logtag>.))? (?<log>.*)$/
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 512Mi
            cpu: 500m
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /var/log/
#        - name: varlibdockercontainers
#          mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
        - name: dockercontainerlogsdirectory
          mountPath: /var/log/pods
          readOnly: true
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: varlog
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log/
 #     - name: varlibdockercontainers
 #       hostPath:
#          path: /var/lib/docker/containers
      - name: dockercontainerlogsdirectory
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log/pods
```

Deployment Steps.

```
apt install apache2-utils -y

# It will prompt for a password, pass a password.
htpasswd -c auth admin 

kubectl create secret generic basic-auth --from-file=auth

kubectl create ns logging

kubectl apply -f elasticsearch-logging-statefulset.yaml

kubectl create configmap kibana-config --from-file=kibana.yml

kubectl apply -f kibana-logging-deployment.yaml

kubectl apply -f kibana-ingress-ssl.yaml

kubectl apply -f fluentd/fluentd-sa-rb-cr.yaml

kubectl apply -f fluentd/fluentd-daemonset.yaml
```